# How do I add data from a form to nested object in firebase angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add userdata to my angular fire object.

This is what my database structure looks like:

[image: This is what my database structure looks like.]

I am trying to add data to the roles object using this code
 
             Admin

```
         <label> Dealer</label>
         <input type="checkbox"  name="roles{dealer}"  #userRole="ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "user.roles.dealer" [checked]="user.roles.dealer">

           <label> Manager</label>
           <input type="checkbox" name="roles{manager}" #userRole="ngModel" [(ngModel)] = "user.roles.manager" [checked]="user.roles.manager" >
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a form so I can collect all the checkbox properties. This example is a template-driven form. On submit you can send the values to Firebase with a service. See an example at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whvqmq).

```
<div>
<form #rolesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm(rolesForm.value)">
  <label> Dealer</label>
  <input type="checkbox"  name="manager" [(ngModel)]="user.roles.dealer" [checked]="user.roles.dealer">
  <label> Manager</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="dealer" [(ngModel)]="user.roles.manager" [checked]="user.roles.manager" >
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<pre>FormData {{ rolesForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

In your component:

```
  logForm( val ) {
    this.user.roles = val;
    console.log(val);
    // Handle changes to Firebase.
  }
```